# SPBuiltInFieldId in CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, spfield

Is there any alternative to `SPBuiltInFieldId`  in csom /SharePoint
    online?

Should you only reference field only by `InternalName` in csom/SharePoint
    online?

Comment: I'm not clear about question...Are you want to get field by internal name?

Comment: I was looking for the SPBuiltInFieldId  in SPO/CSOM, but I noticed I couldnt find it. If it has been removed, Im thinking that maybe its not recommended anymore to user field ids. So: (1) is it still there for csom (2) if not, is the reason bec you shouldnt use guids anymore

Comment: Not sure, But it seems that "SPBuiltInFieldId" OR Same alternative class is not available in CSOM.

Comment: Agreed, just wondering if there are some other way. I could of course whip up a BuildInffieldId-class of my own, but maybe its not recommended. Seems like MS has dropped the notion of documenting sp online, so Im keeping this question open here